# Both public and private socket.io connection in SPA

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, authentication, socket.io

So I have a webapp that has two types of users. Public users who have not yet authenticated and private users who have logged in and authenticated themselves. I am using token based authentication in single page app, there are no page refreshes after the page is initially loaded. So user first comes to site and is unauthenticated, has no token available to him. He then authenticates which returns a token to him that can be used to check that he is authenticated on the server side by node.js. Now I also have some real time messages that I am sending from node.js to the client. There will be two types of messages. I need to send public messages to both public and private clients and also after a client has authenticated I need to be able to send private messages to the authenticated user (for example when his account balance changes in the database I want to send the private client a notification). These private messages should be protected.

Now I am a bit confused as to what is the best practice of achieving this.

What's the best way to have both public and private socket.io available in a single page app?

And I am using angular.js on the clientside but this is probably not relevant (using https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)

Thank you very much if you can help me out and point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io provide some tools like rooms or namespaces to help.

In your case, i think the best solution is to have two namespaces. One for not logged user, and one for logged user.

You can use authorisation on one namespace only if you need.

Then you can broadcast in a namespace in particular if needed.

```
io.of('/user').on('connection', function (socket) {
     //Manage socket
}

io.of('/operator').authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
    if(isAuthorized){
        callback(null,true);
    }else{
        callback(null,false);
    }
}).on('connection', function (socket) {
    //Manage the socket
}

io.of('/operator').emit('msg', { text:text});
```